# Inserting a tree-like dataset into MySQL using a python script

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, tree, hierarchical-data

Hello I am very new to MySQL. I am facing some issues to inserting a large "tree-like" data into my database.

**DATA:** I have a tree-like data of various topics, subtopics, sub-subtopics and so on. I have written this into a yml file. Here is the small portion of that yml file.

```yaml
mathematics:
  - algebra:
    - linear_and_multilinear_algebra:
      - vector_spaces
      - matrix_operations
    - group_theory
  - analysis:
    - real_analysis
    - complex_analysis
    - functional_analysis:
      - integral_equations
      - differential_equation:
        - ode
        - pde
      - operator_theory
      - operator_algebra:
        - c*-algebras:
          - c*-algebras_and_their_representations
          - operator_spaces_associated_with_c*-algebras
          - kk-theory_and_k-homology_of_c*-algebras
          - non-selfadjoint_operator_algebras
        - banach_algebras
        - von_neumann_algebras:
          - non-commutative_geometry
          - factors
          - tomita_takesaki_theory

        - operator_spaces
        - non-commutative_algebras
natural_sciences:
  - biology:
    - botany
    - zoology
    - microbiology:
      - virology
      - bacteriology
  - chemistry:
    - organic_chemistry
    - inorganic_chemistry
    - physical_chemistry
  - physics:
    - classical_mechanics
    - quantum_mechanics:
      - quantum_entanglement
      - quantum_field_theory
technology_and_engineering:
  - computer_science:
    - algorithms
    - data_structures
    - artificial_intelligence:
      - machine_learning
```

**MySQL Database:** To store this data I have created the following tables in MySQL

```sql
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS knowledge;
USE knowledge;

-- Table to store topics
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS topics (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

-- Closure table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS closure (
    ancestor INT NOT NULL,
    descendant INT NOT NULL,
    length INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ancestor, descendant),
    FOREIGN KEY (ancestor) REFERENCES topics(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (descendant) REFERENCES topics(id)
);
```

> **Problem.** I want to write a python script that can read the yml file and populate the two tables.

I have written the following script but it gives ERROR.

**Code**

```py
# Load the YAML data from your file
with open(cat_config_file, 'r') as yaml_file:
    data = yaml.load(yaml_file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

# Establish a connection to the MySQL database
db_connection = mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)

# Create a cursor object to interact with the database
cursor = db_connection.cursor()

# Recursive function to insert topics and build the closure table
def insert_topic(topic, parent_id=None, level=0):
    # Insert the topic into the topics table
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO topics (name) VALUES (%s)", (topic,))
    topic_id = cursor.lastrowid

    # Insert the closure record for the current topic and its parent with level
    if parent_id is not None:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO closure (ancestor, descendant, length) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (parent_id, topic_id, level))

    # Recursively insert subtopics
    if isinstance(data[topic], list):
        for subtopic in data[topic]:
            insert_topic(subtopic, topic_id, level + 1)
            
# Iterate through the top-level topics and insert them
for top_level_topic in data.keys():
    insert_topic(top_level_topic)

# Commit changes and close the cursor and connection
db_connection.commit()
cursor.close()
db_connection.close()

print("Data inserted into the MySQL database, with hierarchy levels in the 'closure' table.")
```

**ERROR**

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "book_category.py", line 54, in <module>
    insert_topic(top_level_topic)
  File "book_category.py", line 50, in insert_topic
    insert_topic(subtopic, topic_id, level + 1)
  File "book_category.py", line 40, in insert_topic
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO topics (name) VALUES (%s)", (topic,))
  File "/home/indrajit/Documents/hello_world/mysql/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 317, in execute
    prepared = self._cnx.prepare_for_mysql(params)
  File "/home/indrajit/Documents/hello_world/mysql/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 802, in prepare_for_mysql
    result = self._cmysql.convert_to_mysql(*params)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Python type dict cannot be converted
```

Please help me to fix the code. Thanks.

**PS.** I want to add that I'll query the db to get all parents of a particular node. For example, if I enter `pde` then it should return `mathematics > analysis > functional_analysis > differential_equation > pde`

Comment: The data model you're using makes little sense for a tree structure, where each node should be a self-referencing model with a single foreign key to its parent. You can use an additional field to describe if the node is a dict, a list or a value, and another field to hold the key or index to the parent container.

Comment: @blhsing you mean something like
```CREATE TABLE topics (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    parent_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES topics(id)
);
```

Comment: Yes, but with the two additional columns as mentioned to describe the kind of container it is and its key/index to the parent container, e.g. `CREATE TABLE topics (     id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,     name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,     parent_id INT,     type ENUM('dict', 'list', 'value'),     key VARCHAR(255),     FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES topics(id) );` On second thought, `key` should only be used when the parent container is a dict; when the parent container is a list, `key` should be `NULL`, and the order of the row id can be used to determine the order of the sibling nodes.

Comment: The "closure table" method is useful as a denormalized way to store hierarchies in legacy MySQL 5.x instances. If you are using MySQL 8.x, you can make recursive queries, so it's easier to use data in normalized format (with the `parent_id` as described). I compared different solutions in a 2017 presentation: https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/recursive-query-throwdown

Comment: @BillKarwin I checked my version (using mysql --version) it gives ```mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.42, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper```. What should I use then?

Comment: @BillKarwin Ah, I get how a closure table can be used to describe a tree structure now. I guess one can add a `key` colum to the closure table to store the key to a dict parent when the depth (or length as the OP names it) is 1. The row id can again be used to determine the order of the immediate children of a list. And the type of a node can be stored in the node table itself (the `topics` table in the OP's example).

Comment: @blhsing could you please elaborate it in an answer if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The error has nothing to do with closure table or even SQL. It's a problem purely in Python, about how you are traversing your YAML structure.

You start inserting the hierarchy:

```
for top_level_topic in data.keys():
    insert_topic(top_level_topic)
```

The `data.keys()` returns a list of strings, which are keys of the top of the hierarchy. Strings are scalars, and these can be used as parameters for your INSERT statement.

But when you try to do the recursive step to insert the next level of the hierarchy, you pass the Python dict referenced by the topic you just inserted.

```
        for subtopic in data[topic]:
            insert_topic(subtopic, topic_id, level + 1)
```

You didn't use `subtopic.keys()`, thus `subtopic` is a dict, not a string.

Also, the recursive function will always be referencing `data[topic]` at the top of the hierarchy. Even if you pass subtopic keys, they will be trying to find that key at the top of the hierarchy.

I would design this recursive function to accept the dict, and examine the keys of that dict itself.

Then you would start the first step as:

```
insert_topic(data)
```

I'll leave it to you to decide how you want to design the code in that function to traverse the YAML structure, since it has both dicts and tuples. YAML is a bit more complicated than simply a tree.